# How to post data using json from html table to controller in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have view which contains `salesmain` and `salesub` details

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
<TABLE >
<tr>
<td>
<label id="lblBuyerName" style="color: white">BuyerName</label>
</td>
<td>
<input type="text" name="txtBuyerName" id="BuyerName" style="width: 250px;"/>
</td>

</tr>
<tr>
<td>
<label id="lblDate">Date</label>
</td>
<td>
<input type="text" name="txtDate" id="tDate" style="width: 100px; height: 15px;" />
</td>

</tr>

</TABLE>

<div style="background-color: lightsteelblue; min-height: 125px; min-width: 50px; border-bottom: ActiveBorder; padding-right: 500px;">
<TABLE id="dataTable" border="3" style="padding-left: 49px; margin-left: 10px;">
<tr>
<td>
SELECT
</td>
<td>
REGION
</td>
<td>
QUANTITY
</td>
<td>
RATE
</td>
<td>
AMOUNT
</td>
<td>
TAX PERCENTAGE
</td>
<td>
TAX AMOUNT
</td>


</tr>
<TR>
<TD><INPUT type="checkbox" name="chk"/></TD>
<TD> @Html.DropDownList("country", new SelectList(ViewBag.ListOfDisciplines, "Value", "Text", Model)) </TD>
<TD> <INPUT type="text" name="Quantity" id="Quantity"/> </TD>
<td>
<input type="text" name="Rate" id="Rate" />
</td>
<td>
<input type="text" name="Amount" id="Amount" style="width: 100px; color: green" readonly="true"/>
</td>
<td>
<input type="text" name="TaxPer" id="TaxPer" style="width: 100px; color: green" readonly="true"/>
</td>
<td>
<input type="text" name="TaxAmt" id="TaxAmt" style="width: 100px; color: green" readonly="true"/>
</td>
</TR>
</TABLE>
<input type="button" value="Add Row" onclick=" addRow('dataTable') " style="border-left-width: 1px; margin-left: 10px;"/>
<input type="button" value="Delete Row" onclick=" deleteRow('dataTable') " />
<br />
<div style="font: italic small-caps bold 20px georgia, garamond, serif;">
<table >
<tr>
<td style="margin-left: 1px; padding-left: 1px;">Grand_Total:</td>
<td><input type="text" readonly="true" name="grand_total" id="grand_total" style="width: 100px; color: green"/></td>
<td>All_Tax:</td><td> <input type="text" readonly="true" name="All_totalTax" id="All_totalTax" style="width: 100px; color: green" /></td>
<td>All_Total:</td><td> <input type="text" name="All_total" readonly="true" id="All_total" style="width: 100px; color: green" /></td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
</div>
<div>
<input type="submit" id="btnSaveALL" value="Save Record" style="border-left-width: 1px; margin-left: 10px;"/>
</div>
}
```

And my Ajax function is

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
          $(document).ready(function () {
                    $(function () {
                        $("#tDate ").datepicker();
                    });

                    $("#btnSaveALL").click(function () {

                        $.ajax({
                            type: "POST",
                            url: "Sales/ShowTable",
                            success: function (response) {
                                alert('Document Saved.');
                            }
                        });
                    });
                });
    </script>
```

and the controller action method is:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult ShowTable()
{
    return View();
}
```

`txtBuyerName`, `txtDate`, `grand_total`, `All_total`, `All_totalTax` columns all belong to the `salesmain` class.

`country`, `Quantity`, `Rate`, `Amount`, `TaxPer`, `TaxAmt` columns all belong to the `salessubs` class

I want to post all data to controller using jQuery json. Then what should be jQuery ajax function and controller method code be?

Thank you in advance...

Answer (score 0):

You could start by writing a view model that will represent the data you want to submit (you might need to adjust the data types of the various properties depending on your specific requirements):

```
public class SalesViewModel
{
    public string Country { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
    public decimal Rate { get; set; }
    public int Amount { get; set; }
    public decimal TaxPer { get; set; }
    public decimal TaxAmt { get; set; }
}

public class MyViewModel
{
    public string BuyerName { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public decimal AllTotal { get; set; }
    public decimal AllTotalTax { get; set; }
    public SalesViewModel[] Sales { get; set; }
}
```

and then:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('#tDate').datepicker();

        $('form').submit(function () {
            var sales = [];
            $('#dataTable tr').each(function() {
                sales.push({
                    country: $('td select', this).val(),
                    quantity: $('td input[name="Quantity"]', this).val(),
                    rate: $('td input[name="Rate"]', this).val(),
                    amount: $('td input[name="Amount"]', this).val(),
                    taxPer: $('td input[name="TaxPer"]', this).val(),
                    taxAmt: $('td input[name="TaxAmt"]', this).val(),
                });
            });
            var model = { 
                buyerName: $('#BuyerName').val(),
                date: $('#tDate').val(),
                allTotal: $('#All_total').val(),
                allTotalTax: $('#All_totalTax').val(),
                sales: sales
            };
            $.ajax({
                url: this.action,
                type: this.method,
                contentType: 'application/json',
                data: model,
                success: function (response) {
                    alert('Document Saved.');
                }
            });

            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
```

and now your controller action could take the view model as argument:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult ShowTable(MyViewModel model)
{
    ...
}
```

This being said your HTML is pretty broken. You have duplicate ids which is not allowed. Also a further improvement step would be to use this view model as model to the view and generate the input fields with strongly typed helpers such as `Html.EditorFor` instead of hardcoding them as you did. This will allow you to greatly simplify the AJAX call because you would no longer need to be mapping between the name of your input fields and the property names of the view model. The default model binder will be able to bind them by convention:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('#tDate').datepicker();

        $('form').submit(function () {
            $.ajax({
                url: this.action,
                type: this.method,
                data: $(this).serialize(),
                success: function (response) {
                    alert('Document Saved.');
                }
            });

            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
```